# How to just replace url with anchor except youtube url?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a function that checks for HTTP links and replaces them with anchor tags if they exist. If there is a YouTube URL, it replaces it with an iframe. I'm having trouble finishing it since I can't figure out how to just add an anchor for those URLs that aren't YouTube URLs.

Here's the functions

```
export const renderLinkWithText = (text = '') => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
  const newText = text.replace(replacePattern1, '<a class="anchor_link" target="_blank" href="$1">$1</a> ')
  return newText.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />').replace(/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?.*v=)?(\w+)/g, '<iframe width="100%" height="350px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
}
```

Comment: How about a simple `.include('youtube')`, don't overdo regexp it hurts it performance...

Comment: Didn't got you?

Comment: I single string may have a both sometime a normal link & a youtube link

Answer (score 0):

You would want to include a negative lookahead in your 1st pattern with which to exclude youtube urls. Something along the lines of:

```
(?!(www.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be))
```

The entire pattern would than become:

```
(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/(?!(www.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])
```

Edit:
I've corrected the initial answer, you test your regular expressions online. https://regex101.com/ for one accepts the above.

Comment: Could you please check because I think that not working for me

Comment: I've edited the answer, not testing is a recipe for mistakes ;)

Comment: Ah thank able to help in improving the youtube url regx?

Comment: Basically, if the text has more than 1 youtube link it's not showing the text or iframe except the 1st

Comment: I want to replace all the link with iframe not just the 1st

Comment: I think you're regex was not working as expected

Comment: Try changing the order of replace statements in the last line of code, 1st replace the youtube links, than replace the new lines.